# Binding PyQT ProgressBar to compilation (simultaneous execution of other code)

Tags: python, user-interface, installation, progress-bar, pyqt6

`Hi, I am having this trouble - I do not know, how to bind progress bar to a "compilation" - i mean the Progress bar would respect the compilation time or at least it can run somehow "slowly", because now once I hit "next" at the first page, it shows 100% (and yes, I playd with the Worker "do_work" and tried to set the time.sleep many times to a diferent value)

Thanks for helping me out

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QStackedWidget, \
    QProgressBar, QLineEdit
from PyQt6.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal as Signal, pyqtSlot as Slot
import time
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSignal as Signal
import ssh_paramico
import templates
import os


class CompilationThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.text = None

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def run(self):
        # Your compilation code here
        new_script_content = templates.new_script_content
        temp_script_path = "temp_script.py"
        with open(temp_script_path, "w") as temp_script:
            temp_script.write(new_script_content)

        os.system(f"pyinstaller --onefile {temp_script_path}")

        os.remove(temp_script_path)
        os.remove("temp_script.spec")



class Worker(QObject):
    progress = Signal(int)
    completed = Signal(int)

    @Slot(int)
    def do_work(self, n):
        total_iterations = n * 2  # We have two sleeps per iteration
        for i in range(1, total_iterations + 1):
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Adjust the sleep time to a reasonable value
            self.progress.emit((i * 100) // total_iterations)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    work_requested = Signal(int)
    name_input_text_requested = Signal(str)


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('QThread Demo')

        self.stacked_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked_widget)

        # Introductory Page
        self.intro_widget = QWidget()
        intro_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.intro_widget.setLayout(intro_layout)
        intro_label = QLabel("Welcome to this one")

        #server_label = QLabel("Server IP:")
        #self.server_label = QLineEdit()

        ip_label = QLabel("IP:")
        self.ip_label = QLineEdit()
        # print(self.name_input)

        #intro_layout.addWidget(server_label)
        #intro_layout.addWidget(self.server_label)

        intro_layout.addWidget(ip_label)
        intro_layout.addWidget(self.ip_label)

        intro_layout.addWidget(intro_label)
        self.btn_next = QPushButton('Next', clicked=self.show_progress_page)
        intro_layout.addWidget(self.btn_next)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.intro_widget)

        self.compilation_thread = CompilationThread()
        self.compilation_thread.finished.connect(self.handle_compilation_finished)

        # Progress Page
        self.progress_widget = QWidget()
        progress_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.progress_widget.setLayout(progress_layout)
        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress_bar.setValue(0)
        progress_layout.addWidget(self.progress_bar)
        self.finish_label = QLabel("Work is complete!")
        self.finish_label.hide()
        progress_layout.addWidget(self.finish_label)
        self.btn_finish = QPushButton('Finish', clicked=self.show_finished_page)
        self.btn_finish.hide()
        progress_layout.addWidget(self.btn_finish)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.progress_widget)

        # Finished Page
        self.finished_widget = QWidget()
        finished_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.finished_widget.setLayout(finished_layout)
        finished_label = QLabel("FINISHED")
        finished_layout.addWidget(finished_label)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.finished_widget)

        self.worker_thread = None
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.update_progress)
        self.worker.completed.connect(self.complete)
        self.work_requested.connect(self.worker.do_work)

        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.intro_widget)
        self.show()
        self.name_input_text_requested.connect(self.handle_name_input_text)


    def handle_compilation_finished(self):
        self.complete(None)

    def handle_name_input_text(self, ip):
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.progress_widget)
        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(lambda: self.work_requested.emit(3))
        self.worker_thread.start()


        #I NEED THIS TO WAIT FOR A PROGESS BAR... THE PROGRESSBAR IS TOO QUICK AND ITS STILL COMPILING WHEN THE PROGRESS BAR SHOWS "DONE"

        self.compilation_thread.set_text(ip)
        self.compilation_thread.start()


        self.worker_thread.quit()
        self.worker_thread.wait()
        self.worker_thread = None

        self.complete(None)  # Call the complete method to show the finish label and button

    def show_progress_page(self):
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.progress_widget)
        self.name_input_text_requested.emit(self.ip_label.text())  # Emit the signal
        self.start_work()

    def show_finished_page(self):
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.finished_widget)

    def start_work(self):
        if self.worker_thread is not None and self.worker_thread.isRunning():
            self.worker_thread.quit()
            self.worker_thread.wait()
            self.worker_thread = None

        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(lambda: self.work_requested.emit(10))
        self.worker_thread.start()

    def update_progress(self, v):
        self.progress_bar.setValue(v)

    def complete(self, _):
        self.btn_next.setEnabled(True)
        self.finish_label.show()
        self.btn_finish.show()
        self.progress_bar.setValue(0)  # Reset progress bar value to 0
        self.progress_bar.setMaximum(len(self.ip_label.text()))  # Set maximum value for progress bar
        self.progress_bar.setValue(len(self.ip_label.text()))  # Set progress bar value to maximum
    def finish(self):
        self.finish_label.hide()
        self.btn_finish.hide()
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.intro_widget)

    def compilation(self, text):
        # Create a new script content with the static IP
        new_script_content = templates.new_script_content

        # Write the new script content to a temporary file
        temp_script_path = "temp_script.py"
        with open(temp_script_path, "w") as temp_script:
            temp_script.write(new_script_content)

        # Compile the temporary script into an executable
        os.system(f"pyinstaller --onefile {temp_script_path}")

        # Clean up temporary files
        os.remove(temp_script_path)
        os.remove("temp_script.spec")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Your implementation is extremely convoluted. It's not clear why you're using two threads (and two different ways to using them), but in any case: 1. calling `wait()` right after `start()` is wrong because it's blocking; 2. calling `quit()` is useless since the thread will not "quit" until it's finished what it's doing; 3. continuously creating threads is pointless: you're always waiting for the previous to end, so you should *reuse* the QThread instead; 4. you should consider QProcess instead of QThread/`os.system`, since its interface allows better management/monitoring of external processes.